# Are there Lebesgue-measurable functions non-continuous almost everywhere?

Tags: measure-theory

My intuition keeps telling me that being continuous Lebesgue-almost everywhere is highly restrictive and that being measurable is not. But I've not been able to come up with a not continuous a.e. function e.g. $[0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$. So

- Are there not continuous a.e. functions?
- Are there Lebesgue-measurable ones?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let
$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0 & \text{if }x\in\mathbb{Q},\\
1 & \text{if }x\notin\mathbb{Q}.
\end{array}\right.$$
Then $f(x)$ is Borel- (hence Lebesgue-) measurable, since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable; it is also discontinuous everywhere, hence almost everywhere not continuous.

---

Regarding the comments made below, we have

**[Lusin's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luzin%27s_theorem)**. If $f\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$ is measurable, then for every $\epsilon\gt 0$ there exists a compact $E\subseteq [a,b]$ such that $f|_E$ is continuous and $\mu(E^c)\lt\epsilon$.

This is the best you can hope for, as for instance the characteristic function of a [fat Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_Cantor_set) shows, as noted [in this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38989/nearly-but-not-almost-continuous).

Comment: As this example shows, one needs to be careful. "Continuous a.e." (i.e. the set of discontinuities has measure 0) is most definitely not the same as "equal to a continuous function a.e."

Comment: Ah, well as @kahen said I meant *not a.e. equal to a continuous function*. I'll post the appropriate question. Good point though :)

Comment: Just a typo : *not a.e. equal...*

Comment: @Evpok: So you want an example of a function $f(x)$ that is (i) Lebesgue measurable; and (ii) not equal almost everywhere to a continuous function. Correct?

Comment: @Evpok: You could just *add* the correction to this one...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: It would make your answer seem not accurate, and I think I may not be the last to make this mistake.

Comment: @Evpok: That's why I had said "add"; in any case, I think what you are looking for is more along the lines of Lusin's Theorem. Given a measurable function $f\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, for every $\epsilon\gt 0$ there is a continuous function that is equal to $f$ outside an open set of measure less than $\epsilon$. I think that's the best that you can say (i.e., there are examples where you do not have equality almost everywhere with a continuous function).