# Are there Lebesgue-measurable functions not almost everywhere equal to a continuous function

Tags: measure-theory

This is why I originally meant to ask with [Are there Lebesgue-measurable functions non-continuous almost everywhere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/67055/15102)

Does there exist a function $f\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that:

1. $f$ is Lebesgue measurable; and
2. For every continuous $g\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, the set of points where $f(x)\neq g(x)$ has positive measure?

Comment: On the other hand, see [Lusin's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luzin%27s_theorem).

Comment: The question listed as duplicate is actually a stronger statement.  For this one, $f = 1_{[0,1/2]}$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  Fix any measurable set $A$ such that both $A$ and its complement have non-null intersection with each nonempty open interval.  Examples are discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57317/construction-of-a-borel-set-with-positive-but-not-full-measure-in-each-interval).  Then the characteristic function of $A$ is as desired, since removing a null set does not change this intersection property, which rules out having a continuous extension.